# PHP: Building Smooth Image Transitions on the Fly

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick, php-gd

I'm trying to figure out via PHP if I can do the following. Imagine I have a two images. The first is an image of a square (50px by 50px). The second image, is that exact same square, only offset by 5px to the left.

I'm wondering if there is a way to dynamically generate all the images in-between to make this a smooth looking image transition (ie in this case generate the other 4 images to make it look like it moved from left to right).  This would be a pretty simple situation, however would be applied to more complex images with the exact same premises, essentially using two images to predict the mediums.

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php would only be a wrapper, think eval() and google it, like http://www.linuxfocus.org/English/September2001/article139.shtml

regards,
/t

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best thing you could hope to do with PHP is to do a 'morph' animation, where you sample the pixels for the first image and the second image, then create a third image consisting of the average color values. Repeating this process you could create as many sub-frames as you would like, but the result would be a blurring / morphing of image A -> image B, and would only be perceived as an animation with the simplest of input images.

More complicated algorithms including edge-detection or hinted-shape tweening could be utilized and implemented, however PHP might not be the best choice for this.

Comment: is there another language you could recommend which would be better at this? Thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically create images with a combination of PHP and ImageMagick.

You can pass in each dimension to ImageMagick, and it will generate an image on the fly for you. Create an image for each pixel you offset, resulting (in this case) in four extra images you can use later for your animation.

Comment: I've used ImageMagick very little, do you have any examples online of where to find anything talking about this? Thanks!